# Exchanging metadata with local-directory

Tags: appexchange, version-control

I have salesforce sandbox and IDE (I want to go around the fact, the IDE can download repo). My question is quite hipotetically. 
Is there some tool similiar to SourceTree, which could be able to pull&push changes just from my sandbox to local-directory and vice versa?

I am aware, that is smth like AutoRabit, but it is ruining my work cost. Anyway I would like to get know about payable plugins and opensource ones if they exists.
I would be very grateful for any information about.

Comment: Sorry I just figured it out that there is no word in Eng like vice vers. It means: "also in opposite way"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you checked force.com cli https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/forcecli . Maybe import/export options will suite you.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted